# Creating .bat file to sort files with similar pattern anywhere in string

Tags: java, batch-file, cmd

I'm stuck and unsure of how to progress, I would like to create a .bat file that can search through a directory (and eventually sub directories) and pick up files with similar names and either move them or copy them into a new folder based on that name.

For instance, I have these files in a documents directory:

> ```
> apples101.txt
> 101apples.txt
> 201applesohmy.doc
> 203apples101course.txt
> 101oranges.txt
> orangesohmy101.txt
> peeltheoranges.txt
> orangejuice.txt
> ```

and I would like to move all the files with "apple" in their name to a folder called Apple and all the files with "Orange" in their name into a folder called orange.

The key point to it though is that the search should automatically pick up like files based on pattern and not something I dictate. What I mean to ask is if there is a way so that rather then me having to put apple into the delim string and then running another set of commands with orange in it, is there a loop I can do that would basically search though all the files and sort like files into their own directory?

I know I can use tokens without a delim option string but then it wouldn't search the files to match the name.

Perhaps it would be better to take the first file name (excluding file extension) maybe say matching 6 characters in the name, and run the file name against the rest of the file names to find a pattern match and then move those files into a new folder with a like name? Then loop it for the remaining files?

Would this be possible?

Would this be possible in maybe java without the need to compile the script?

Comment: Java is a compiled language, so no

Comment: This sounds like a soundex. I wouldn't even consider doing it in pure batch. I'd use SQLite for that part.

Comment: Crud I have no experience with SQLite; the main thing about this script is that it needs to work on a target computer that most likely does not have a compiler or would be able to get one. But for SQLite I'm guessing I would just have to make an array from the files sort the array and then just use some sort of match command?

Answer (score 0):

This type of problems are difficult to solve because the number of rules involved. However, we *may* develop a "proof of concept" program in order to test how it behaves with real data and then try to improve it introducing new rules.

The Batch file below process each file name dividing it in a substring each time smaller, count the number of files that match the substring and stop as soon as this number is greater than one, but only when the substring does not start nor end in digit. As said before, this method may be improved introducing new rules.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set MAX_FILE_LEN=30
set DIGITS=0123456789

for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir /B /A-D') do if exist "%%a" (
   set "fileName=%%~Na"
   for /L %%i in (1,1,%MAX_FILE_LEN%) do if "!fileName:~%%i,1!" neq "" set len=%%i
   ECHO/
   ECHO FILENAME="!FILENAME!", LEN=!LEN!
   set "baseName="
   for /L %%i in (!len!,-1,2) do if not defined baseName (
      set /A last=len-%%i+1
      for /L %%j in (0,1,!last!) do if not defined baseName (
         set "testName=!fileName:~%%j,%%i!"
         for /F "tokens=1,2" %%a in ("!testName:~0,1! !testName:~-1!") do (
            if "!DIGITS:%%a=!" equ "%DIGITS%" if "!DIGITS:%%b=!" equ "%DIGITS%" (
               for /F %%n in ('dir /B /A-D "*!testName!*.*" ^| find /V /C ""') do set num=%%n
               if !num! gtr 1 set "baseName=!testName!"
            )
         )
      )
   )
   if defined baseName (
      echo BaseName found: !baseName!, moving files:
      if not exist "!baseName!" md "!baseName!"
      move "*!baseName!*.*" "!baseName!"
   ) else (
      echo File name unique: !fileName!
      if not exist UniqueFiles md UniqueFiles
      move "*!baseName!*.*" UniqueFiles
   )
)
```

Output example:

```
C:\test> dir /B
101apples.txt
101oranges.txt
201applesohmy.doc
203apples101course.txt
apples101.txt
orangejuice.txt
orangesohmy101.txt
peeltheoranges.txt

C:\test> ..\test

FILENAME="101apples", LEN=8
BaseName found: apples, moving files:
C:\test\101apples.txt
C:\test\201applesohmy.doc
C:\test\203apples101course.txt
C:\test\apples101.txt
Se han movido         4 archivos.

FILENAME="101oranges", LEN=9
BaseName found: oranges, moving files:
C:\test\101oranges.txt
C:\test\orangesohmy101.txt
C:\test\peeltheoranges.txt
Se han movido         3 archivos.

FILENAME="orangejuice", LEN=10
File name unique: orangejuice
C:\test\orangejuice.txt
Se han movido         1 archivos.
```

**EDIT**: *New rule added*

This type of solutions depends on the data. This means that a "perfect solution" for a particular data is not guaranteed to be obtained, just a solution "better than the last one" if possible. The solution below introduce an additional rule: it gets successive base names as the number of matching files increases, but only if the length from previous base name differs in just one character.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set MAX_FILE_LEN=30
set DIGITS=0123456789

for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir /B /A-D') do if exist "%%a" (
   set "fileName=%%~Na"
   for /L %%i in (1,1,%MAX_FILE_LEN%) do if "!fileName:~%%i,1!" neq "" set len=%%i
   ECHO/
   ECHO FILENAME="!FILENAME!", LEN=!LEN!
   set "baseName="
   set "lastName="
   set /A lastNum=0, lastLen=0
   for /L %%i in (!len!,-1,2) do if not defined baseName (
      set /A last=len-%%i+1
      for /L %%j in (0,1,!last!) do if not defined baseName (
         set "testName=!fileName:~%%j,%%i!"
         for /F "tokens=1,2" %%a in ("!testName:~0,1! !testName:~-1!") do (
            if "!DIGITS:%%a=!" equ "%DIGITS%" if "!DIGITS:%%b=!" equ "%DIGITS%" (
               for /F %%n in ('dir /B /A-D "*!testName!*.*" ^| find /V /C ""') do set num=%%n
               if !num! gtr !lastNum! (
                  if !lastLen! equ 0 (
                     set "lastName=!testName!"
                     set /A lastNum=num, lastLen=%%i-1
                  ) else if %%i geq !lastLen! (
                     set "lastName=!testName!"
                     set /A lastNum=num, lastLen=%%i-1
                  ) else (
                     set "baseName=!lastName!"
                  )
               )
            )
         )
      )
   )
   if not defined baseName set "baseName=!lastName!"
   if !lastNum! gtr 1 (
      echo BaseName found: !baseName!, moving files:
      if not exist "!baseName!" md "!baseName!"
      move "*!baseName!*.*" "!baseName!"
   ) else (
      echo File name unique: !fileName!
      if not exist UniqueFiles md UniqueFiles
      move "*!baseName!*.*" UniqueFiles
   )
)
```

Comment: Thank you Aacini, this is very close if not perfect to what I am looking for. Quick question, I tried changing the gtr value to see what happens and instead of 1 used 4 but I get unexpected results. for instance with !num! gtr 1 ; oranges was the base name found but with !num! gtr 4 oran was the base name found.  Why is that?

Comment: Yes. There is no way to know which one is the right number that give better results (4?, more?, less?). I added a new method that _may_ produce better results in your real data. Please, report the result...

Comment: The new rule definitely works with my sample set the way I wish for it to. I will try this on the target computer and get back with results.